# What does an empty setup.cfg do?

Tags: python

What does an empty `setup.cfg` do in a Python project? Does it do anything? Why would you add one?

https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python/commit/c04c49b0e57197f97cc55697c2d37a2ff82827b5

Comment: Are we using Setuptools, distutils, or something else?

Comment: @Kevin: [`setuptools`](https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python/blob/master/setup.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.cfg` contains *optional* configuration tweaks. An empty `setup.cfg` has the same effect as no `setup.cfg` file at all. It is a place to store pre-defined command line options for the `setup.py` script, and just like it is fine to not use command line options it is fine to provide an empty `setup.cfg` file.

Since `setup.cfg` is aimed at users and projects installing or packaging the project, an empty file could make it easier for those users to figure out where to put it in the first place. Rather than ask users to create it, you only have to ask them to edit the existing file.